# Shifted bits values

Tags: java, bit-shift, bit

```
String message = "1";
        byte[] bytes = message.getBytes();

        System.out.println(bytes[0] + ": ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            System.out.print((bytes[0] >> (7 - i)) + " ");
        }

Output: 49: 
0 0 1 3 6 12 24 49
```

So my string is `1` which in ASCII is `49`. What I'm trying to understand is why do my bits have values 3,6,12,24 and 49? What's happening behind, why aren't they only 0 and 1 like the first 3?

Comment: Write the binary representation of `49` on your notebook, with a pencil. And keep on shifting 1 by 1 for 8 times, and see on each turn what value you get.

Comment: I get it. Is there a way I can print each sequence as binary?

Comment: Yes, you can perform an `&1` on the result, to obtain the last bit.

Comment: An alternative in this case is to use `Integer.toBinaryString(i);` with `i` the number to print.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

49 in binary is

```
110001
```

You shift this same value by `7, 6, 5, 4, ..., (7 - i)` bits.

So

```
00110001 >> 7 ==> 00000000 == 0
00110001 >> 6 ==> 00000000 == 0
00110001 >> 5 ==> 00000001 == 1
00110001 >> 4 ==> 00000011 == 3
...
```

You can use [`Integer.toBinaryString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toBinaryString%28int%29) to get the binary representation of an integer value as a `String`.

Comment: Is there a way to print those values in java?

Answer (score 2):

Because your bit extraction is incorrect.  The bit representation for the character `'1'` is that of `49`: `00110001`.

You are shifting 7 times, then 6, then 5, etc., but you are not isolating the bits properly.

```
00110001 >> 7 is 00000000 or 0
00110001 >> 6 is 00000000 or 0
00110001 >> 5 is 00000001 or 1
00110001 >> 4 is 00000011 or 3
00110001 >> 3 is 00000110 or 6
00110001 >> 2 is 00001100 or 12
00110001 >> 1 is 00011000 or 24
00110001 >> 0 is 00110001 or 49
```

You must do a bitwise-and with `1` to isolate the bit you've shifted to get the 1s and 0s out.

```
System.out.print( ((bytes[0] >> (7 - i)) & 1) + " ");
```

Output:

```
49: 
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The last 8 bits of number `49` in binary looks like this:

```
00110001
```

When you shift the number right by `k` bits, it's the same as dividing it in `int` by 2<sup>k</sup>. That is what you get in the output (digits to the right of `|` are dropped):

```
0 | 0110001 -- 0
00 | 110001 -- 0
001 | 10001 -- 1
0011 | 0001 -- 3
00110 | 001 -- 6
001100 | 01 -- 12
0011000 | 1 -- 24
00110001 |  -- 49
```

Answer (score 0):

When shifting, you shift the bits `n` positions (in this case to the right).

So:

```
Loop#    7-i     bits      result
0        7      000000000   0
1        6      000000000   0
2        5      000000001   1
3        4      000000011   3
4        3      000000110   6
5        2      000001100  12
6        1      000011000  24
7        0      000110001  49
```

The reason why the first shifts are `0` and `1` is because al significant bits were already shifted out.

If you want to obtain the last bit, you need to perform `(a>>s)&1` with `a` the number and `s` the bit from right you want.

In case you want to print the binary representation of `a`, you can simply use `Integer.toBinaryString(a);`

Answer (score 0):

Your actual data might be 49 but, it needs to fill 8 bit for byte data types.So, if you count 8 bit starting from 0 to 7 (as per your loop).And you are using `>>` which will right shift.

```
49 binary is  0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1

0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1  >> 7-0 = 00000000 = 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1  >> 7-1 = 00000000 = 0
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1  >> 7-2 = 00000001 = 1
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1  >> 7-3 = 00000011 = 3
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1  >> 7-4 = 00000110 = 6
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1  >> 7-5 = 00001100 = 12
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1  >> 7-6 = 00011000 = 32
0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1  >> 7-7 = 00110001 = 49
```